# Send located File in oneDrive to user using bot composer

Tags: bots, botframework, onedrive, bot-framework-composer

Hi guys(I hope you are doing well),

I have a file (.csv) located in OneDrive and want send it to user using bot composer. I used Adaptive Card in my bot but when I write the address of my file (located in OneDrive) in url of Adaptivecard it doesnt work. can you please help me how can I fix it ?

Thanks

Comment: OneDrive file is in public or private?

Comment: Hi, first thanks for the reply, it's private.